# How to compile 2 less files in 2 !!! css file in a specific place?

Tags: css, webpack, less

The initial layout in less. It is necessary to make, that media requests were disconnected -> the basic styles we take out in app.less, media - in media.less. Now you have to compile 2 css files from them and put them in a certain place.

For a basis took [https://github.com/vikpe/react-webpack-babel-starter] here this pig. Here webpack 3, more or less a fresh reagent and so on.

I put less-loader, I prescribe in common.js

```
{
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [{
            loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
        }, {
            loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
        }, {
            loader: "less-loader" // compiles Less to CSS
}],
},
```

in the react-component I import: import 'assets / less / app.less'; and import 'assets / less / media.less';

All works, but less was not recompiled in a css-file and it was built in html. Not the same. Next, the option for selling is indicated in the docks (Typically, it is recommended that you extract the style sheets to a separate file created with ExtractTextPlugin, so your styles do not depend on JavaScript.) I change the prod.js to

```
// production config
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const {resolve} = require('path');

const commonConfig = require('./common');

const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

const extractLess = new ExtractTextPlugin({
filename: "[name].[contenthash].css",
disable: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
});

module.exports = merge(commonConfig, {
    entry: './index.js',
devtool: 'source-map',
output: {
filename: 'js/bundle.[hash].min.js',
path: resolve(__dirname, '../../dist'),
publicPath: '/',
},
module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: extractLess.extract({
            use: [{
                loader: "css-loader"
            }, {
                loader: "less-loader"
            }],
            // use style-loader in development
            fallback: "style-loader",
      publicPath:"/css/"
        })
    }]
},
plugins: [
    extractLess
]
});
```

I start npm run start-prod and as a result:
1. All styles are written in one css file (and I need it in 2), and not the one where I pointed in publicPath.
2. In the npm-debug.log errors

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'D:\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'D:\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'start-prod' ]
2 info using npm@4.0.5
3 info using node@v7.4.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart-prod', 'start-prod', 'poststart-prod' ]
5 info lifecycle react-webpack-babel-starter@0.1.0~prestart-prod: react-webpack-babel-starter@0.1.0
6 silly lifecycle react-webpack-babel-starter@0.1.0~prestart-prod: no script for prestart-prod, continuing
7 info lifecycle react-webpack-babel-starter@0.1.0~start-prod: react-webpack-babel-starter@0.1.0
8 verbose lifecycle react-webpack-babel-starter@0.1.0~start-prod: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle react-webpack-babel-starter@0.1.0~start-prod: PATH: D:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;F:\react-webpack-babel-starter-master-less\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\daima\bin;D:\Git\mingw64\bin;D:\Git\usr\local\bin;D:\Git\usr\bin;D:\Git\usr\bin;D:\Git\mingw64\bin;D:\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\daima\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Files\cpp\bin\Intel64;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;D:\Git\cmd;D:\nodejs;D:\Skype\Phone;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem;D:\Visual Studio Code\bin;C:\Users\daima\AppData\Roaming\npm;D:\Git\usr\bin\vendor_perl;D:\Git\usr\bin\core_perl
10 verbose lifecycle react-webpack-babel-starter@0.1.0~start-prod: CWD: F:\react-webpack-babel-starter-master-less
11 silly lifecycle react-webpack-babel-starter@0.1.0~start-prod: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'npm run build && node express.js' ]
12 silly lifecycle react-webpack-babel-starter@0.1.0~start-prod: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle react-webpack-babel-starter@0.1.0~start-prod: Failed to exec start-prod script
14 verbose stack Error: react-webpack-babel-starter@0.1.0 start-prod: `npm run build && node express.js`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (D:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:279:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (D:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:885:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
15 verbose pkgid react-webpack-babel-starter@0.1.0
16 verbose cwd F:\react-webpack-babel-starter-master-less
17 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
18 error argv "D:\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "start-prod"
19 error node v7.4.0
20 error npm  v4.0.5
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error react-webpack-babel-starter@0.1.0 start-prod: `npm run build && node express.js`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the react-webpack-babel-starter@0.1.0 start-prod script 'npm run build && node express.js'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the react-webpack-babel-starter package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     npm run build && node express.js
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs react-webpack-babel-starter
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls react-webpack-babel-starter
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

How to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

To get two css output files, you need to use two instances of the ExtractTextPlugin and configure two rules.

[From the documentation](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin#multiple-instances)

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

// Create multiple instances
const extractApp = new ExtractTextPlugin('stylesheets/[name]-one.css');
const extractMedia = new ExtractTextPlugin('stylesheets/[name]-two.css');

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /app\.less$/,
        use: extractApp.extract([ 'css-loader', 'less-loader' ])
      },
      {
        test: /media\.less$/,
        use: extractMedia.extract([ 'css-loader', 'less-loader' ])
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    extractApp,
    extractMedia
  ]
};
```

Comment: And if they are in the same directory?

Comment: The regex works if they are in the same directory. It just looks if the file name ends with app.less or media.less